# How to combine all elements of two dynamically created arrays and write the results into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to build my own "keyword shuffler" (eg. for Google Ads). For this I have created an HTML5 document with two input fields and one output field.

The idea is: You can write an arbitrary number of words (separated by comma) into each of the input fields. Then, if you click on a button, the output-field shows all possible combinations (pairs) of the two input-fields, with the condition, that the first word comes from 'input1' and the second word from 'input2'.

Additionally: I want to manipulate the output rows (eg. add some characters, such as '' or + or [] ), but this can be another question:)

I can already extract the inputs and convert them into two arrays. To combine them, I have made a nested 'for .. of' function. In my console.log i can already see all the results, but in my 'output'-field there is only the last combination.

```
function keywordShuffler(){

var kw1_array = ['keywordA','keywordB','keywordC']; // an abritrary number of keywords

var kw2_array = ['keyword1','keyword2','keyword3','keyword4']; // an abritrary number of keywords

for (value of kw1_array){

    for (value2 of kw2_array) {

      var output = value + ' ' + value2;
      document.getElementById("output").value = output;
      console.log(output);                 // to test the output
      }
  }
}
```

My expected output:

> keywordA keyword1
>  keywordA keyword2
>  keywordA keyword3
>   keywordA keyword4
>  keywordB keyword1
>  keywordB keyword2
>   keywordB keyword3
>  keywordB keyword4
>  keywordC keyword1
>   keywordC keyword2
>  keywordC keyword3
>  keywordC keyword4

what I get:

> keywordC keyword4

Comment: You're simply overwriting the element every time through the loop, not adding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value from each iteration. You can assign to the output element at the end of the loop.

```js
function keywordShuffler() {
  var kw1_array = ['keywordA', 'keywordB', 'keywordC']; // an abritrary number of keywords
  var kw2_array = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3', 'keyword4']; // an abritrary number of keywords
  var output = '';
  for (value of kw1_array) {
    for (value2 of kw2_array) {
      output += value + ' ' + value2 + '\n';
      document.getElementById("output").value = output;
    }
  }
}

keywordShuffler();
```

```html
<textarea id="output" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try appending the output to an element other than replacing previous value with new value.

```
document.getElementById("output").value += output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
  function keywordShuffler(){

    var kw1_array = ['keywordA','keywordB','keywordC']; 

    var kw2_array = ['keyword1','keyword2','keyword3','keyword4']; 

    for (value of kw1_array){

     for (value2 of kw2_array) {

    var output = value + ' ' + value2 + '<br>';

     document.getElementById("outputs").innerHTML += output;
    console.log(output);                
       }
     }
  }
```

```html
  <button onclick="keywordShuffler()">click me to check</button>

  <span><div id="outputs"> outputs....</div></span>
```